# Youtube video embed responsive size in flexbox row

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm stuck with attempts to make embedded youtube videos list responsive.

1. Each video should be with max-width let's say 300px.
2. If window size is less, than video should shrink.
3. If window size is big, than videos should get in rows.

Problem with current code is that max video height don't want to be as specified in Preview - max-height: 500px.

Any ideas?

[Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/bitter-sea-36pq2).

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**.

Comment: @Pete it's not debugging, but ideas is what i'm looking for.

Comment: Still off topic for SO then

Comment: @Pete what is the difference with any other question on SO?

Comment: @Pete added a specific problem, if it's will help somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this partially with @media:

```
const Preview = styled.div`
  iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
`

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .games-list div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 300px) {
  .games-list div {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  .games-list div {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .games-list div {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a good use case for a CSS grid with `auto-fill`. Here's an example in which boxes of 300px wide wrap. You can adapt that to your specific needs.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <style>
      .boxes {
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 300px));
      }
      .box {
          height: 100px;
      }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="boxes">
    <div style="background-color: red;" class="box"></div>
    <div style="background-color: blue;" class="box"></div>
    <div style="background-color: pink;" class="box"></div>
    <div style="background-color: green;" class="box"></div>
    <div style="background-color: black;" class="box"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Problem is that youtube embedded with iframe and it works strange :(

Answer (score 1):

For scaling videos in CSS, particularly `iframe` elements within `div`s, I use the old padding ratio / relative:absolute positioning trick.

I've got a gist here if you want to use it (with optional JS for detecting ratio):

https://gist.github.com/robertpauldev/cad3ccaed608692f495707b9eebbf70c

If you don't want to use the JS, you can hard-code your own ratio, e.g. 16:9 ( height / width * 100 ).

A uniform 16:9 video ratio would therefore be achieved with `.video-wrap { padding-bottom: 56.25%; }`

That would get the scaled videos sitting more flush with one another, particularly in **CSS Grid** setup.